# importing complex XML data into multiple FileMaker tables

Tags: xml, xslt, import, filemaker

I understand the basics of import to FileMaker (csv, xml) and I know a little about XSLT.

I have a data set containing lists that I need to import into FileMaker. There are 3 tables for this - the main table, the datapoints table and the positions table. My data looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<result>

<data mode="test" ram="on">
    33,869
    34,115
    46,074
    225,233, E
    226,122, E
    235,763, E
    237,408, E
    237,722, E
    242,503
    256,271
    273,741
</data>

<statistics>

    <positions>
        <position id="1" unit="c">0,00</position>
        <position id="2" unit="c">5,05</position>
        <position id="3" unit="c">14,30</position>
        <position id="4" unit="c">23,47</position>
    </positions>
</statistics>    
</result>
```

how do I import this XML into FM in one go? I understand I need to convert it to fmpxmlresult, but everything I've read assumes that the XML is essentially a fancy CSV - individual rows without related/sub-rows.

And yes, the *positions* data is properly XML'ified, and the *data* data is newline-seperated and I know that's not the XML way, but it's the way I receive the data.

Is there something I can do to make this easy for my users? I can pre-process the data outside of FileMaker if absolutely necessary, but would like to avoid that if possible.

(split off from this question - [Export and Import date from/into current record only in FileMaker 18](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62256971/export-and-import-date-from-into-current-record-only-in-filemaker-18) - which contained a simplified version of this question and an unrelated other question, someone remarked I should ask one question at a time)

Comment: Please post a **complete** (even if minimal) example of the input XML. What you show is missing a root element and the `<statistics>` start-tag is orphaned. Also clarify what exactly you want you to import to where, and how it needs to be linked; ATM I don't see any connection between `positions` and `data`.

Comment: @michael.hor257k completed the XML. I'm relatively free in where to import it to. And yes, positions and data are not connected, they just belong to the same result set.

Comment: You still didn't say what exactly you want to import to where. The data points seem to have one or two three values each - and that's in addition to the `mode` and `ram` attributes.

Comment: I want to import all data. I don't particularily care how my FM tables need to be as I'm in control of that and can build them in any way needed. And yes, the data I receive is as in the example, though that's one or two elements - European notation, 5,05 is five-point-zero-five, not two comma-seperated records.

Comment: You need to know your target table's structure **before** you can write an XSLT stylesheet that will populate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To import the `positions` into a table with fields for `PositionID`, `Unit` and `Value`, you can use the following stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns="http://www.filemaker.com/fmpxmlresult">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/result">
    <FMPXMLRESULT>
        <METADATA>
            <FIELD NAME="PositionID"/>
            <FIELD NAME="Unit"/>
            <FIELD NAME="Value"/>
        </METADATA>
        <RESULTSET>
            <xsl:for-each select="statistics/positions/position">
                <ROW>
                    <COL>
                        <DATA>
                            <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
                        </DATA>
                    </COL>
                    <COL>
                        <DATA>
                            <xsl:value-of select="@unit"/>
                        </DATA>
                    </COL>
                    <COL>
                        <DATA>
                            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                        </DATA>
                    </COL>
                </ROW>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </RESULTSET>
    </FMPXMLRESULT>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

To import the `data` into a table with two target fields (not sure what to call them), you can use:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns="http://www.filemaker.com/fmpxmlresult">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/result">
    <FMPXMLRESULT>
        <METADATA>
            <FIELD NAME="A"/>
            <FIELD NAME="B"/>
        </METADATA>
        <RESULTSET>
            <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="data"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </RESULTSET>
    </FMPXMLRESULT>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="tokenize">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:param name="delimiter" select="'&#10;'"/>
    <xsl:param name="sep" select="', '"/>
    <xsl:variable name="token" select="normalize-space(substring-before(concat($text, $delimiter), $delimiter))" />
    <xsl:if test="$token">
        <ROW>
            <COL>
                <DATA>
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(concat($token, $sep), $sep)" />
                </DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring-after($token, $sep)" />
                </DATA>
            </COL>
        </ROW>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="contains($text, $delimiter)">
        <!-- recursive call -->
        <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, $delimiter)"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: That's brilliant. Now I just need to figure out how to let the user select a file once, then import it three times with three different XSLTs.

Comment: Let the user insert the file into a variable (as reference only). Use the variable as the file path for the three imports.

Comment: Thought along the same lines, but still relatively new to FM, so I'm trying to figure all those things out. :-)

Answer (score 1):

The import procedure is still as I described in my answer on the question you link to. You need an XSLT file to specify during import to transform your XML to FileMaker's schema. This is not very difficult with a simple source file, but still necessary.

Comment: There used to be simple XML example files included with FileMaker, but that does not seem to be the case anymore. I can send you these files if you want.

Comment: that would be very useful, and yes, I am missing an example in the documentation.

Comment: You can download the examples from this temporary link. https://www.dropbox.com/s/sz7fpxo9f4mtpx5/FileMaker_XML_Examples.zip?dl=0

Comment: Thanks a lot, that will certainly help.

Answer (score -1):

Here's how you can simplify the triple-import for the users:

- create a global container
- place it on the layout (or on a temp layout specifically for this process)
- in your script use the Insert File script step to let the user choose a file
- set it up to always insert a reference, no zipping, no choice
- then you can GetAsText the container and extract the path into a variable $filePath
- after that you can use the variable $filePath to specify the file in the proceeding imports and set them to run with no dialog.

Voila!

I don’t know why this answer has been voted down. It is a suggestion how to solve the Corresponding problem of choosing a source file once but performing two imports, as the poster asked in his reaction to the solution above.